# Removing something from array but game crashes

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx

I have and array where I create few swords on the tiled map and when i step on them they need to be deleted but when I step on them game chrashes.

at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)

MY CODE:

I guess the loop is looking for the object even if its deleted?

```
private List<Sword> swords = new ArrayList<Sword>();
```

I create them one time:

```
public GameRender(GameWorld world, int gameHeight) {
    for (int i = 0; i<100 ; i++ ) {
        swords.add(new Sword());
        }
```

When i step on it:

```
for (Sword sword : swords) { 
        if(playery+7>=sword.position.y && playery+7<=sword.position.y+tilesize
        && playerx+7>=sword.position.x &&playerx+7<=sword.position.x+tilesize) {
                sword.pickMe();   
                swords.remove(sword);
        }
    }
```

There is other loop in render():

```
for (Sword sword : swords) {
        sword.createMe();
    }
```

I dont think you need to see the Sword class. If you do i'll put it in here. How do i fix it so I dont get the error?

Comment: `ConcurrentModificationException` because you're using the enhanced for loop, thus implicitly an iterator. You cannot modify the list you are iterating while you are iterating it.

Comment: I'm sorry I dont really understand. I don't know english about coding well. Could you show me in code how this works?

Comment: I posted an answer in the meantime as well :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (Sword sword : swords) { 
        if(playery+7>=sword.position.y && playery+7<=sword.position.y+tilesize
        && playerx+7>=sword.position.x &&playerx+7<=sword.position.x+tilesize) {
                sword.pickMe();   
                swords.remove(sword); //this line throws ConcurrentModificationException
        }
}
```

Due to how the enhanced `for` loop works, you either need to use an `Iterator<Sword>` to remove it:

```
Iterator<Sword> iterator = swords.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext())
{
    Sword sword = iterator.next();
        if(playery+7>=sword.position.y && playery+7<=sword.position.y+tilesize
        && playerx+7>=sword.position.x &&playerx+7<=sword.position.x+tilesize) {
                sword.pickMe();   
                iterator.remove();
        }
}
```

Or the following:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < swords.size(); i++) { 
        Sword sword = swords.get(i);
        if(playery+7>=sword.position.y && playery+7<=sword.position.y+tilesize
        && playerx+7>=sword.position.x &&playerx+7<=sword.position.x+tilesize) {
                sword.pickMe();   
                swords.remove(i--);
        }
  }
```